# How to clean build files in python without setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

By invoking directly `setup.py`, it is possible to remove the build directory via `python setup.py clean --all` (not to mention [other options](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/cleaning-build-directory-in-setup-py))

As invocation to `setup.py` is now discouraged, is there any way to do the same for projects not having a `setup.py` file at all and built with `python -m build` and a `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: No obvious solution. Related discussion: https://discuss.python.org/t/-/13741/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a setup.py file and you want to clean build files in a Python project, you'll need to manually identify and delete the relevant files and directories. Typically, build files are generated in the process of running various tools or scripts, and their location may vary depending on the tools used.

1. '**pycache**'
2. '*.pyc'
3. '.swp'
4. 'build'